# Set seperate alphas for each line in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, transparency, line-plot

I want to build a graph with ggplot using geom_line. I made up the following reprex to expose the problem:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(Value = rnorm(20), 
                        Obs = c(1:10,1:10),
                        Var = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
                        Alpha = c(rep(0.7, 10), rep(0.99, 10)))
     
ggplot(data, aes(x = Obs, y = Value, col = Var, alpha = Alpha)) +
       geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I want the "A" variable to be a little bit more transparent than the "B" variable. So I set alpha to 0.7 and 0.99 inside the dataframe for "A" and "B" respectively. However, this produces a plot with "A" much more transparent than "B". In fact, changing alpha to say 0.95 does not change the appearance at all.

I would be very thankful for some guidance.

Comment: Try `alpha=as.factor(Alpha)`.  Or `... + scale_alpha_discrete(...)`.  By default, `ggplot` uses a continuous scale for transparency.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `scale_alpha_identity` to your plot. This allows the value of `Alpha` to be interpreted literally as the value of alpha you want for your line:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Obs, y = Value, col = Var, alpha = Alpha)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your alpha aesthetic to be determined by `Var` and then use a discrete scale.  It will issue a warning because the `ggplot2` authors think this is a weird thing to do.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Obs, y = Value, col = Var, alpha = Var)) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(limits = c("A","B"), range = c(0.7, 0.99), guide = FALSE) + 
  geom_line()
```